# Converting Powershell output to Python array

Tags: python, arrays, powershell, active-directory

I have exported a list of active users from an Active Directory in Powershell through a Python script, I now want to save the list of names as an array in Python so that i can use it further in my program.

I have the list of namen from the active directory printed in the command prompt but do not seem to get the data into my Python script. When i try to print the data in Python i get the string: `<Popen: returncode: None args: ['powershell.exe', 'C:file/location...>`. In Powershell i used the `Write-Output` command.

This is the code i am using now:

```
def gebruikers_ophalen():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "C:/file_locationLis/script.ps1"], stdout=sys.stdout)
    time.sleep(7)
    Geb_lijst = p
    print(Geb_lijst)
```

Comment: You will need a parser that both languages understand (e.g. Json). I don't know Python very well but I guess something like: `p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-Command 'C:/file_locationLis/script.ps1 |ConvertTo-Json'"], stdout=sys.stdout); Geb_lijst = json.loads(p)`

Comment: If you have a lot of data, save it into a file in Powershell script (pass filename as parameter to the script) and read it later in Python.